# replace or remove evince

Tags: uninstall, evince, okular

I want to use my own document viewer (okular) and never want to see evince again.

In Ubuntu 13.04 when I try 'dpkg -P evince' it says that ubuntu-desktop depends on it.

Comment: While I approve that this is a huge problem, this is not a constructive question (or a question at all for that matter). Please improve to an answerable question.

Comment: You could just make your program as the default program (easy enough to do, just google it) and then you would never have to use evince again. Problem solved!

Comment: What happens if you try `update-alternatives --config gnome-text-editor` ?   If it only lists gedit, you could redirect /usr/bin/gedit manually.

Comment: if you want those thumbs downs removed, I suggest you refer to the [faq](http://askubuntu.com/faq) and [this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrogative_word) in order to rephrase your question.

Comment: And having a username of 'who cares' is not exactly encouraging people to answer this.

Answer (score 6):

You should not use the `dpkg` command directly to manage packages in general, but should use the `apt-get` command instead. It is generally safe for the `ubuntu-desktop` package to be removed, as it is a meta-package that only depends on other packages. Nothing should be depending on it.

Simply doing `sudo apt-get remove --purge evince` will show you what packages exactly will need to be removed as a result of evince's removal. You can accept or deny the transaction. If you accept, then `evince` and `ubuntu-desktop` will both be purged, as will any other packages which `apt-get` lists as needing removal when you run the command.